# how to write "++i" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I searched online but could not find an answer. I know i+=1 in Python is equivalent to i++ in C/C++. But what about ++i? when I want to increment first and then assign. Is it never used in Python and why it is not needed?

I searched online for an answer but could not find one.

Comment: `i+=1` is _not_ equivalent to `i++`, as `+=` is a *statement* and does not return a value; neither the pre- nor post-incremented value. Thus the question for a pre-increment equivalent is moot.

Comment: Or from another perspective, `i += 1` is equivalent to *both* `i++` and `++i` when used as standalone statements, where the distinction between pre- and post-increment is irrelevant.

Comment: I do not agree that it is a duplicate question. The question tagged does not say anything about if I can write "++i" in Python!

Comment: The duplicate tells you why there is neither `++` nor `--` in *any* form. The comments above slightly expand on this. I have no idea what more you expect.